Can 1 SF org be linked to multiple SFMC instances (NOT BUs within 1 instance, but different SFMC logins / instances / businesses)
I've received a client request: they want to know if a single SF core org can be connected to more than one SFMC instance /  different logins. The request specifies that these are not multiple Business Units within one SFMC instance, but rather two separate SFMC instances/logins (think like  two distinct businesses).
From my research, most of the available documentation addresses the multi-org setup where one SF org is connected to multiple Business Units within the same SFMC instance.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mktg.mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5
https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/implementing-marketing-cloud-with-multiple-salesforce-orgs-part-2-fd639fb44226
https://www.sfmcsimplified.com/multi-org-account-configuration-in-marketing-cloud-connect-use-case-part-1/
**However, in this case, the client’s goal is to use a single SF org to connect with two completely independent SFMC instances.
**Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!
Read available articles
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mktg.mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5
https://medium.com/salesforce-architects/implementing-marketing-cloud-with-multiple-salesforce-orgs-part-2-fd639fb44226
But they all say about connection to different SFMC BUs within the same instances
However, the request is to use a single SF org to connect** with two completely independent SFMC instances / logins
**
